# Change one color of a CMYK image

Tags: php, imagick, cmyk

I have an image in RGB that I convert to CMYK like this :

```
$img->transformimagecolorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
```

But now, I want to convert all the white parts of the image to an other color. So 
**cmyk=0%,0%,0%,0%** to **cmyk=0%,0%,3%,0%**. But I don't want the entire image to be converted, only the white parts.

How should I do please ?

Comment: `$img->transformimagecolorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);` doesnt convert to CMYK, it does convert to RGB (as you're clearly passing RGB). See http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.transformimagecolorspace.php.

Comment: @FabianSchöner But when I'me using COLORSPACE_CMYK, it doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to achieve this. [FX expressions](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php), or [`Imagick::opaquePaintImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.opaquepaintimage.php), for example.

If your just starting out with raster images, I would recommend working with pixel iterators.

```php
$img = new Imagick('wizard:');
// Force CMYK color channels.
$img->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
// Calculate `3%' once.
$yellowValue = $img->getQuantum() * 0.03;
// Copy pixel data into an iterator.
$pixelIter = $img->getPixelIterator();
// Iterate over pixel rows.
foreach($pixelIter as $row) {
  // Iterate over pixels.
  foreach($row as $pixel) {
    /*
       We can call `ImagickPixel::isPixelSimilar', but it might be quckier to
       use an accumulator.
     */
    $sumOfColors = $pixel->getColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_CYAN)
                 + $pixel->getColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_MAGENTA)
                 + $pixel->getColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_YELLOW)
                 + $pixel->getColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_BLACK);
    if ($sumOfColors == 0.0) { // Is `WHITE'?
       $pixel->setColorValueQuantum(Imagick::COLOR_YELLOW, $yellowValue);
    }
  }
  // Copy values back to image.
  $pixelIter->syncIterator();
}
```

Note that we are calculating & setting the `3%` value against the quantum color.

[image: Change one color of CMYK image]